# How different about “trailing zero” and “trailing zeros”

Tags: word-usage, difference

How different about “trailing zero” and “trailing zeros” and I’m wondering about “leading zero” and “leading zero” If I put -s trailing word what is mean?[image]

Comment: Screenshots are really bad for readability across the board as well as accessibility for visually impaired people. Can you put a link there in its place?

Comment: "How different about “trailing zero” and “trailing zeros”".  Would you mind clarifying the question?  Is it about the difference between singular (zero) and plural (zeros)?

Comment: One "Traling Zero", two or more "Trailing Zeros". It's just as simple as that.